# Is there any proof or reference about the age or time at what Swami Vivekananda's predicted himself not living more than forty years?

Tags: vivekananda

This [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23054/did-vivekananda-prophesy-he-would-die-before-the-age-of-40-why-didnt-he-prolon) and the answer talks about Vivekananda's prophecy of him not living more than forty years.

But I could not find at what age or which year he actually predicted.

Also, it's mentioned by only other authors. There's no concrete proof I could find that says he himself predicted this.

I checked even Wikipedia page but it only briefly talks about this topic. Not much information.

**Is there any proof or reference about the age or time at what Swami Vivekananda's predicted himself not living more than forty years?**

Comment: At a speech given in response to his felicitation by the local gentry held at Pogos School of Dhaka in 1901, Swami Vivekananda stated that he had less than a year  to live. The fact statement that he wouldn't live upto the age of 40 was stated in a letter written by him to one of his gurubhais.